# textBox parsing in C#

Tags: c#

I have problem with parsing from textBox in C#. Basically I am trying to set some value to integer and after that when person type number in text box if it's the same to increase counter. But i must to parse int to string and here i am failing.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace kontrolno {
  public partial class Form1: Form {
    int counter;
    int A = 13;
    int B = 2116;
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      label3.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      int A = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
      if (textBox1.Text = A) /*As you see somewhere here i have a problem*/
    }
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      /*Here must be parsed second textBox*/
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex) //comboBox 1st case
      {
      case 0:
        button1.Enabled = false;
        textBox1.Text = "13";
        textBox2.Text = "2116";
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        /*Those 3 answers should 
        checkBox2.Checked = true;   be counted as one 
        checkBox4.Checked = true;  when mark is formed*/
        checkBox5.Checked = true;
        break;
      case 1:
        /*comboBox 2nd case*/
        button1.Enabled = true;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
        checkBox2.Checked = false;
        checkBox4.Checked = false;
        checkBox5.Checked = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (radioButton1.Checked) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (checkBox1.Checked) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (checkBox2.Checked) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (checkBox4.Checked) {
        counter++;
      } else {
        counter--;
      }
    }
    private void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (checkBox5.Checked) {
        counter++;
      } else {
        counter--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So i have problem but i don't know how to fix it.The idea of that code is to be test.The comboBox have 2 items in 1st item Practice user see all questions and answers.In 2nd item user filling up the answers and when press button he receive his mark.I haven't implemented yet formula for mark because can`t get result from textBox.

Also i want to ask is it possible to get 3 answers from checkBoxes to be counted as one?

It should be simple but i just crashed and can`t reslove that problem.

Comment: Way too much code. Rule of thumb: If there are scrollbars, it is too much.

Comment: I read this a couple of times and I still have no idea of what you are trying to do or your problem is. Maybe you could try rewriting this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you seem to have the assignment operator (=) and equality operator (==) mixed up. If you want to compare the content of the textbox with a value, you should use the equality operator:

```
if (textBox1.Text == A)
```

Note that you should get a compile error on this line, since the Text property returns a string object, and the A variable is an int, so you'd need to parse the Text property and maybe assign it to a second local variable before testing. You can use `Int32.Parse` like you did on the line above, but I'd recommend using `Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out A)` so that no exception is raised when the text is not in a valid numerical format.

Answer (score 0):

problem 1, your 
`if (textBox1.Text=A)` SHOULD be something like `if(textbox1.Text==A.ToString())`

classic assignment/equality error

but even that is odd, I have no idea why you'd wanna parse the value of the textBox1 to an int, and then see if the value of the parsed int is equal to what you just parsed?  totally odd.  You've already defined int A outside of the scope, and declared it again inside the scope.  If you're trying to tell if the new value equals the old value, you've could just qualify `if(a==this.A)` .  Or do the sane thing and call your local int something else.

But overall, the program is very strange, and I'm not even quite sure what you're asking about.